# Autocomplete material ui

Tags: material-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to add a autocomplete material ui inside a autocomplete material ui. To simply saying I need a dropdown inside a dropdown but I am unsure of how to approach it. Can you give me approach that I can try. Thanks in advacne